# Two columns and one of them boxed

Tags: columns, framed

I would like to place two text (with math expressions) columns and frame one of them, preferably right column; I'm trying to do that with `minipage` environment but I don't know how to frame it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for macro "\lipsum"
\usepackage{amsmath}% for environment "equation*"
\begin{document}
\noindent
\lipsum[2]

{\vspace{0.5cm}\hfill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}%
{\hspace*{1cm}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation*}
        \hbar = 2\pi h
    \end{equation*}
    \\
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}%
{\hfill\vspace{0.5cm}}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Which produces that

[image]

Now I would like to frame right column. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code you've written that you don't like if the answer below (currently) is not what you are looking for. What may be clear to you from your description may not be clear to many others.

Comment: Well I haven't got any written code because I'm not pretty sure what should I use, `multicol` package, `minipage` environment, and how could I frame the column.

Comment: The code doesn't have to work, but if the table (clearly and obviously to you) doesn't work, we need a better hint. It seems like the *content* of what will be framed matters, but you have not made it clear how or why that matters. Another idea is to draw the desired output and post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\fbox` around the box on the right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \lipsum*[2]
    \begin{equation*}
        \hbar = 2\pi h
    \end{equation*}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}

\bigskip

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Note that `{\vspace{0.5}\hfill}` makes little sense; better using something like `\bigskip`. Also there's no point in doing `{\hspace{1cm}}` (the outer braces are useless, by the way) when `\hfill` will do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, what about `%` when `minipage` environment finish?

Comment: @JFernan You need it only when you don't want a space to creep in; in this case there's none that can make trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer for the question in version [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/337686/1) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/337686/2).
Version [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/337686/3) might be solved using `\fbox{...}` around the `minipage`. But the details (horizontal/vertical spacing, support for page breaks, ...) elude me.

Two columns, the right column is framed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l|l|}
    \cline{2-2}
    abc & def \\
    $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n f(n)$ & $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4} e^{-\sin\alpha}$ \\
    mno & pqr \\
    \cline{2-2}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I was referring to text (with math expressions) columns.

Comment: @JFernan Text is present, math expressions added.

Comment: Check out my MWE :)